# java JOptionPane skip pressing OK button

Tags: java, swing, popup, joptionpane

Hi i have something like this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Config.CHECK_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
System.out.println("go");
// HERE I CHECK MY INTERNET CONNECTION
```

aftter Dialog window popup application has to wait with printing `go` till i press OK button, is there chance to skip it? So that sign `go` will print after window popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `modeless` `JDialog`. See [The New Modality API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/modality/).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's the very nature of an option pane, to halt the execution until got an answer from the user.